Unable to use a PreparedStatement using SQL Server and the NodeJS mssql library
This mssql is the library I'm using for SQL Server.
To make a prepared statement you need to get PreparedStatement object and you need to do:

ps.input
ps.prepare
ps.execute
ps.unprepare

Then handle errors as you go.
router.get('/debtors/', async (req, res) => {
  const column = req.query.column
  
  console.log(column)
  res.send("ok")

  const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(/* [pool] */)
  ps.input('param', sql.VarChar(20))
  ps.prepare('select @param from debtors', err => {
    ps.execute({ param: column }, (err, result) => {
      console.log("Result: " + result);
      ps.unprepare(err => {
      })
    })
  })
})

This code is from the official documentation just tweaked slightly. The URL I'm sending using postman is this:
localhost:8687/debtors/?column=id

console.log("Result: " + result); results in an error:

Result: undefined

I'm not sure why. req.query.column does return the string 'id' and I've set it as a VarChar(20). I've also tried moving @param around to see if there are restrictions.
select * 
from debtors 
where first = @param

So the next thing I tried is this but result is still undefined. I'm not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

What does: err outputs?

Aside... select @param from debtors you can't parameterize column names like that.

@siggemannen hi, I'll post it when I can. Sorry.

@siggemannen hi, this is the error I got from ps.prepare(). ps.prepare err: RequestError

Thanks to @siggemannen I was able to solve the problem. Seeing the error made me think about whether a connection was assigned and I inspected other people's code and realized that when creating a PreparedStatement I needed to pass in the ConnectionPool object from mssql's connect function.
So I made these changes.
// db.js
var pool;

sql.connect(dbConfig).then(result => result = pool).catch(err => {
  console.error("Connection issue: " + err)
  console.error(err.stack)
})

module.exports = { pool, ...}

Then in the file where I needed to use the PreparedStatement
const { pool } = require("db");

// ... code

router.get('/debtors/', async (req, res) => {
  const column = req.query.column
  const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pool) // <--- This is the important part
  ps.input('param', sql.VarChar(200))
  ps.prepare('select * from debtor WHERE first = @param', err => {
    console.log("ps.prepare err: " + err)

    ps.execute({ param: column }, (err, result) => {
      console.log("ps.execute: " + err);

      res.send(result.recordset);
      
      ps.unprepare(err => {
      })
    })
  })
})

The problem was that since I assumed that the callback activated it meant that there was no error. Turns out the callback activates regardless of whether there is an error or not, and to check if there is an error. I need to check if err !== undefined if it isn't undefined then there's an error message in there.
